# Page redirects automatically to front page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a page in two languages, Norwegian and English. The English page, when applying &L=1, only redirects to front page. I have no idea what's wrong.

I tried enable Development settings, but no error. Also I disabled all content elements on page but no change. I disabled RealURL, no change.

TYPO3 6.2.29

Answer (score 1):

maybe you build wrong links in your language switcher.
disable realurl and have a look what links are generated. you probably miss the uid of the current page in the parameter.

how do you generate the language switcher link? language menu?

enhance your question with your configuration.

Comment: Also, have a look at the "pageNotFound_handling" settings in the install tool / All configuration and set it to output an error instead of a redirect. So you'll be able to determine if what you're getting is actually a 404.